# Is it safe to re-use the salt for HKDF as a challenge for proof of possession after key derivation?

Tags: hmac, salt, nonce, hkdf, cmac

I have a system made of 2 or more parties, already sharing a master key `MK`, who want to agree on a session key `SK` (both 128-bit AES keys).

One of the parties (the master) starts the protocol by sending a random nonce authenticated by a MAC computed from a shared secret (derived from `MK`). The request is also protected against replay by means of a counter.

The parties verify the request and compute a salt by concatening nonce, counter and MAC. Then, they use HKDF ([rfc5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869)) based on SHA256 to derive `SK`:

```
PRK = HMAC-SHA256(salt, MK)          // HKDF-Extract
T = HMAC-SHA256(PRK, info | 0x01)    // HKDF-Expand
SK = first 16 octets of T
```

Now, by protocol, each party has to prove that the derivation of SK from MK was successful, by authenticating fresh data with `SK`. Assuming each party has a well-known fixed identifier, I build proof of possession as follows:

```
data = party_ID || salt
proof = AES-CMAC(SK, data)
```

My question is: is it safe re-use the above salt as a "challenge" for proof of possession, or I have to force the master to send a new random nonce as challenge?
With "safe" I mean: assuming that the rest of the scheme is secure, does the fact of re-using the salt as a challenge leak some information about `SK`?

Comment: Is the counter publicly known?

Comment: Yes, the only secret is MK (and SK of course).

Comment: If you have multiple parties, which have to proof the possession of SK, then you cannot just use salt as a challenge for all of them, since any party could just copy the MAC from another one. The challenge needs to be unique per user.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed to specify that the salt is not the only piece of data on which the proof is computed. You're right, question updated.